# Evento OnDisconnected em SignaIR não funciona direito

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

Galera, desenvolvi um chat de acordo [com este link](http://ruchirac.blogspot.co.nz/2013/02/creating-chat-application-in-aspnet.html) e tudo funcionou numa boa. Mas o evento disconnected não funciona direito.

O que acontece é que, de acordo com o link de referência, esse evento é disparado quando o usuário fecha a página, e assim notificando os usuários online que aquele usuário saiu do chat. Só que esse evento não está sendo chamado.

O que acontece é que se eu fecho a guia(a page) esse evento não é disparado e não avisa a sala que o usuário saiu, e mais, esse nome de usuário fica guardado e eu não consigo entrar no chat com o mesmo nome, mesmo quando fechada a guia e tentando abrir de novo.

Pra que eu consiga colocar o mesmo nome, eu preciso esperar o timeout default pra que todo o cookie do site seja excluído...

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Lembrando que todas os outros eventos funcionam, só esse que não

### Aqui os códigos referentes ao evento:

### Na classe que estendo HUB, o método OnDisconnected:

```
 public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Context.ConnectionId.ToString());
        string s;
        dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);
        return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
    }
```

- Aqui já um erro. Eu não posso usar o override :

> 'SignalIRChatMVC.Hubs.MyHub.OnDisconnected()': no suitable method found to override

### O evento em javascript

```
chat.client.disconnected = function (name) {
            //Calls when someone leaves the page
            $('#chats').append('<div class="border"><i>' + name + ' saiu da sala </i></div>');
            $('#onlineList div').remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
            $("#users option").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
        }
```

### E aqui a div que usa pra fazer as manipulações de usuário online ou offline

```
<div style="height: 80%;">
<div id="chats" style="width: 80%; float: left;"></div>
<div id="onlineList" style="width: 19%; float: right; border-left: solid red 2px; height: 100%;">
    <div style="font-size: 20px; border-bottom: double">Usuários online</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Excepção

Relativamente à excepção, o método para fazer *override* do método da classe `Hub` tem a assinatura

```
public virtual Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{...}
```

Assim, o seu `override` ficará:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{...}
```

O método que menciona foi removido na última versão (veja [aqui](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubBase.cs)).

### Vida de uma ligação SignalR

Relativamente ao fim da ligação, em `SignalR` a ligação pode ser terminada das seguintes formas:

- O cliente chama o método `Stop` e uma mensagem é enviada para o servidor a sinalizar o fim da ligação. A ligação é terminada imediatamente.
- A ligação entre o cliente e o servidor cai. O cliente vai tentar voltar a ligar e o servidor vai estar a espera do cliente. Se as tentativas de ligação falharem e o periodo de *timeout* for excedido, tanto o cliente como o servidor param de tentar.
- Se o cliente parar sem ter oportunidade de informar o servidor que vai desligar através do método `Stop`, o servidor espera pelo cliente durante um certo tempo. Se ao fim desse tempo a ligação não for restablecida, o servidor abandona a ligação pendente.
- Se o servidor parar, o cliente vai tentar ligar-se ao servidor durante um certo periodo de tempo. Se ao fim desse tempo a ligação não for restablecida, o cliente abandona a ligação pendente.

No seu caso, deveria prever a primeira situação e invocar o método `Stop` no seu cliente para ter a certeza que os outros utilizadores são informados que o cliente saiu do chat.

### Timeouts de ligação

Relativamente aos `timeouts`, existem 3 distintos que controlam as ligações em `SignalR`:

- ConnectionTimeout: Tempo durante o qual uma ligação permanece aberta. O *default* são 110 segundos;
- DisconnectTimeout: Tempo esperado depois de uma ligação terminar antes de invocar o evento de desconexão. O *default* são 30 segundos.
- KeeepAlive: Tempo esperado entre cada pacote enviado numa ligação passiva. O *default* são 30 segundos. Se colocar este valor a `null`, não são enviados pacotes de `KeepAlive`. Se este tempo estiver activo (não nulo) o `ConnectionTimeout` é ignorado.

Se quiser alterar estes tempos pode fazê-lo da seguinte forma:

```
[assembly:OwinStartup(typeof (StartupConfig))]

namespace Test
{
    public class StartupConfig
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
            GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
            GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
            GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Então se eu trocar o termo override por virtual, ele funcionaria ? Numa boa ?

Comment: Sim, o virtual e como esta definido na classe `base`. Quando faz o *override* so te de substituir o `virtual` por `override`. (estou a editar a resposta relativamente aos meios de terminar a ligação em `SignalR`)

Comment: Nossa @Omni, muito obrigado mesmo ! Estou a algum tempo quebrando a cabeça pra resolver ! Estou na espera da sua edição !